# How do I spawn an Arch Pyromage using console commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can spawn an ordinary Pyromage using the following command:

**player.placeatme 45CBE**

How do I spawn a high level mage? In particular, I'm interested in spawning a Level 50 Arch Pyromancer for testing purposes. In Creation Kit his ID is **EncWarlockFire07BossHighElfM**

Comment: You should be able to find his baseid in Creation Kit, that's the code you need to substitute 45cbe with.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been looking under a different section. I found it under LCharWarlock07BossFire, a container for these characters.

Answer (score 2):

The base ID for Arch Pyromancer is **001091CC**.

The base ID is associated with LCharWarlock07BossFire